# Is std::construct_at on const member safe?

Tags: c++, constants, c++20

I have a class `Obj` with a const member `i`:

```
class Obj {
    const int i;
    ...
};
```

But I need to set i to 0 in my move constructor. (Because if `i` isn't `0`, the destructor will delete stuff, and since I moved the object, that will result in a double free)

Is it safe to modify `Obj::i` in the move constructor like this?

```
Obj::Obj(Obj &&other) :
    i(other.i)
{
    std::destroy_at(&other.i);
    std::construct_at(&other.i, 0);
}
```

From how I understand it, it is safe to do this when `std::construct_at` replaces other.i with a "transparently replaceable object". But I'm not completely sure what the definition means:

> (8) An object o1 is transparently replaceable by an object o2 if:
>
> > (8.1) the storage that o2 occupies exactly overlays the storage that o1 occupied, and
> > (8.2) o1 and o2 are of the same type (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), and
> > (8.3) o1 is not a complete const object, and
> > (8.4) neither o1 nor o2 is a potentially-overlapping subobject ([intro.object]), and
> > (8.5) either o1 and o2 are both complete objects, or o1 and o2 are direct subobjects of objects p1 and p2, respectively, and p1 is transparently replaceable by p2.

(https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-8)

From my understanding, at least 8.1, 8.2, and 8.3 apply, but I'm not completely sure, and I don't really understand 8.4 and 8.5.

So am I correct in thinking this should work (in C++20), or would this result in undefined behavior?

Comment: potentially-overlapping is for base classes and `[[no_unique_address]]`, and 8.5 seems to apply too (for p1 == p2 == other). But why not make it a non-const member?

Comment: @Artyer Ah ok, thank you!
Well, I know making it non-const is an option, but I just think that, since Obj::i is conceptually constant (it never changes, except for when it is moved, and moved objects are never (or should never be) used, only deleted), it should be marked const. Maybe that's a very non-C++ way to think, but that's my reasoning anyways.

Comment: @Artyer Also, if you make an answer about that, I'll accept it (just so I can close the question)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Mh7TTxsYe tried an example, it seems ok.

Comment: I updated a 2d matrix class so that rows and cols are const. Gets rid of the getter functions and provides some protection against inadvertently changing them when writing method code. Had to write the copy/assignment and move specials but worth it. I like the simplicity.

Comment: @doug such simplicity prevents your users from using debug techniques to find out where and how the data is accessed, if they need it.

Comment: They specifically allowed this use case in modern C++, I think C++20. I wonder though if it should be bool or maybe your resource it is tracking should be `std::optional` or `std::unique_ptr``so you don't even have to have a custom move constructor or destructor.

Comment: @Goswin von Brederlow Well, in my actual program, it's an ID for an OpenGL buffer, and 0 works like a nullptr (deleting buffer 0 has no effect). So, it's practically a pointer in that regard. But yeah, in a general use case you're probably correct in saying that those options would be better, but in this case, I'm kinda stuck with just using an int.

Comment: @JoelNiemelä Fair enough. Consider `using OpenGLID = int;` or make a `class OpenGLID` that handles the destruction and movement of just that one `ìnt`. It's best to handle each resource in it's own class separately.

Comment: @Goswin von Brederlow True. Currently, the class that contains that ID only contains 2 other members (ints), and both of them also refer to that GL buffer (its size, etc.). But it might actually still be cleaner doing what you're saying. I will consider it, thank you.

Comment: @ixSci "such simplicity prevents your users from using debug techniques to find out where and how the data is accessed, if they need it." Actually, I find the opposite. It significantly speeds up execution while debugging because accessing the rows/cols no longer has to travel through a getter(). No adverse effect on debugging. rows/cols are invariants during the entire life of a 2D matrix object but they also need to be different between objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A potentially-overlapping subobject is a base class subobject or a member marked with `[[no_unique_address]]`. `Obj::i` is not so 8.4 applies.

If you take p1 and p2 to be the same object, `other`, then 8.5 probably applies (an object can transparently replace itself), except in that it doesn't apply recursively (e.g., `Obj` is a base class/`[[no_unique_address]]` member of some other class, or the complete object it is part of is `const` and `other` has been `const_cast` or is a mutable member). But it will practically always apply.

But consider just not making it a `const` member, since you do need to modify it here. Your move constructor should also clear out `other` (e.g., setting any pointers to `nullptr`, clearing any file handles, zeroing other stuff), so there is no chance for the destructor to accidentally double delete stuff.